# Unity launcher icons squished up under menu bar

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

The Unity launcher on my system has display issues, all the icons are scrunched up under the menu bar. I've restarted my machine, logged into the GNOME session and back into unity, and triple checked the settings in CCSM, but it just stays broken.

It appears to be a display issue, if I right click on the "unused" grey parts of the launcher bar it brings up the context menu for the applications in the correct places, but it just refuses to display them anywhere but mostly hidden under the menu bar.

This is obviously quite irritating. ;)

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the problem:

[image: Annoying Unity Launcher Behaviour]

Comment: I had this same problem and it was so irritating. So my dad (works with computers) restored it to the backup from yesterday, but that didn't end up helping at all. We googled it and came to this page, and he finished updated that weren't opening or showing and then i just restarted the computer and it worked! Yay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same thing happen recently. I installed all of the updates available and rebooted, and that fixed the problem. I suspect that the updates also overwrote some of the configuration changes I made using `gconf-editor`, and I'm now having to go back and redo them.

Comment: There were some outstanding updates for compiz, so I did those, and re-logged in. Issue still oustanding. I'll test a full restart in a while, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: A reboot fixed this, even though logging out and logging back in didn't. No idea what state Unity keeps around when you're still logged out, but apparently it was something! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Never saw that before, but first thing i would done is to

> compiz --replace
>
> reboot

Comment: I tried both of those, nothing. Still broken.